Most appropriate imputation method for dealing with large amount of non-random missing values
I am trying to create a composite index based on the values of several indicators. These indicators give countries a score per year on some dimension they measure. The idea is to determine the relative weights to be assigned to these scores by using a PCA.
However, my dataset contains many missing values. This is because not all countries are scored every year on every dimension.

To run the PCA, I need some way to deal with these missing values. This has proven to be quite difficult, probably largely due to my very basic understanding of statistics.
Ideally, I'd like to impute the data in some way. However, I am struggling to determine what the best method to do this would be. That is firstly because the missing data are not random. If a country is not scored on an indicator in a certain year, it is unlikely to be scored again in other years. The reverse is true as well: countries which do receive a score are likely to be scored again in the year afterwards. Secondly, since my data concern countries which are separate from each other, I cannot impute data from one country to another. It does not make sense if Nigeria receives a score but Norway does not to impute the data to Norway in some way.
Thus I am faced with an issue. Do you have any suggestions on how best to deal with this situation? Or whether it might be best to not impute at all and go for something like NIPALS?
